# How to simply YAML file

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml

I have some repeated key, values in my yaml file.

```
development:
  'pod': 'https://url-dev.mydomain.com/pod'
  'one': 'https://url-dev.mydomain.com/one'
  'two': 'https://url-dev.mydomain.com/two'
  'volume': 'https://url-dev.mydomain.com/volume'
staging:
  'pod': 'https://url-staging.mydomain.com/pod'
  'one': 'https://url-staging.mydomain.com/one'
  'two': 'https://url-staging.mydomain.com/two'
  'volume': 'https://url-staging.mydomain.com/volume'
test:
  'pod': 'https://url-test.mydomain.com/pod'
  'one': 'https://url-test.mydomain.com/one'
  'two': 'https://url-test.mydomain.com/two'
  'volume': 'https://url-test.mydomain.com/volume'
production:
  'pod': 'https://url-production.mydomain.com/pod'
  'one': 'https://url-production.mydomain.com/one'
  'two': 'https://url-production.mydomain.com/two'
  'volume': 'https://url-production.mydomain.com/volume'
```

I read this yaml in my python application to get the URL.

Is there a way to simplify this yaml using variables so that I don't repeat the urls and keys in all environment

Comment: Remove all single quotes from keys.

Answer (score 0):

Create the fields to be *templates* and fill them in the application

```yaml
scope_to_subdomain_map:
  test:        test
  development: dev
  staging:     staging
  production:  production

stubs:
  - pod
  - one
  - two
  - volume

url_base: "https://url-{subdomain}.mydomain.com/{stub}"
```

Then in your application, fill them from the pairs

```py
# imports
config = yaml.load(path)

# read env
scope = os.environ["CUSTOM_KEY_FOR_ENV"]

# verify against valid_scopes, reading out the subdomain name
subdomain = config["scope_to_subdomain_map"][scope]

# fill the collection
urls = []
for stub in config["stubs"]:
    urls.append(config["url_base"].format(subdomain=subdomain stub=stub))
```

If you wanted to produce this for every scope (rather than wherever your application is running), iterate over the mapping instead of reading the scope from the environment (or some other input source)